# Python- how to authenticate with MYSQL [chat database]

Tags: python, mysql, sockets, chat, authentication

I'm scripting a chat program in python...

I'm on chatting program auth but don't know how to script authentication on python-mysql.

How can I authenticate with mysql using python?

Comment: You can have a look at sqlalchemy (http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) it is a Python SQL toolkit and Object Relational Mapper, this can help you.

Answer (score 3):

```
import MySQLdb

dbHost = '127.0.0.1'
dbName = 'chat_db'
dbUser = 'username'
dbPass = 'passwd'

try:
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host=dbHost, db=dbName, user=dbUser, passwd=dbPass)
except MySQLdb.MySQLError, err:
    print "Cannot connect to database. MySQL error: " + str(err)
```

See [mysql-python](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html) for doc & examples

Comment: whera do i insert mysql db? in local host with server code or in the internet host?  where do i insert serve cod in the internet host? my code same of http://snipplr.com/view/46676/

Comment: in this example server and client is inserted in pc

Comment: The database communication, i suppose, should be server side. You can set up the database connection once on server startup and then use it wherever you need it to retrieve or store data in the db table

Comment: i think if i insert mysql db in server start up is dangerous because it can ceacked by user :|

Comment: I don't think I understand your concern. Programming is a dangerous business indeed ;)